# Casting double to int in Qt developer

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I'm having issue with casting double to int in QtDeveloper. As you can see in picture bellow, `x` is integer, and `y` is double. When `int x=static_cast<int>(y)` runs, `x` should be -1, but it is 0. Please any idea why?

For bigger picture click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSn85.jpg)

[image: Screenshot of execution]

Comment: Did you intend to round to the nearest integer, or drop the fractional part?

Comment: I need to drop fraction.

Comment: Try printing the value of x (using cout or printf) and see if you also get 0 instead of -1. If you get -1, then there is some problem with the debugger or the IDE.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any negative exponent at the end of the "Value" field, after the ellipsis ?

Comment: Yes there were negative exponent at the end! You'r king :D

Comment: @alexisdm: I copied your comment as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [alexisdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894321/alexisdm) said in his comment:

> Are you sure there isn't any negative exponent at the end of the
>   "Value" field, after the ellipsis?

Answer (score 3):

Works as intended for me.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void foo(double y)
{
    int x = static_cast<int>(y);
    cout << y << ' ' << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(-1.37026f);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
-1.37026 -1
```

Variable `y` must have different value. It seems to be either bug of IDE that you are using or you are using it wrong ;)

Comment: It works properly, I didn't see negative exponent. But thx for effort.